# update values from textarea in php

Tags: php, html

So..in a textarea I'm bringing the values stored in my table to modify them like this:

```
$l=mysql_query("select * from intrebari where cod_chestionar='".$_SESSION['cod']."'");

echo "<form method='POST' action='lalalalal.php'>";
echo "<textarea  name='edit' cols='50'>";
while($p=mysql_fetch_array($l))

{

   echo $p[denumire_intrebare];
   echo "\n";

}
echo "</textarea>";
echo "<input type='submit' value='Finished' name='save_edit'/>";
echo "</form>";
}
```

It's all fine..the values, that are questions, are brought on separate line. Now I want to make an update if necessary. So in my update file I'm doing like this:

```
$a=$_POST['edit'];

$a_array=explode("\n",$a);


     foreach($a_array as $b)

     {


$sql=mysql_query("UPDATE intrebari set denumire_intrebare='$b' WHERE cod_chestionar='".$_SESSION['cod']."'");
echo $b;
}
```

I want for all questions that have the same cod_chestionar to make the update. In this moment if I make an update the same value is put to all my questions. If I echo it the values are brought to me as I modified them but it doesn't make the update in table. Can you give an opinion because I just can't figure it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using one `<textarea>` for multi records, you have to use separate `textarea`s to be able to modify them and update them separately.

You must have an unique ID field in your `intrebari` table and we will name it `id`, we will use it do solve your problem:

```
<?php

$l = mysql_query("select * from intrebari where cod_chestionar='".$_SESSION['cod']."'");

echo "<form method='POST' action='lalalalal.php'>";

while($p = mysql_fetch_array($l)){
    echo "<textarea  name='edit[".$p['id']."]' cols='50'>"; // Using `id` field here to make array of textareas
    echo $p[denumire_intrebare];
    echo "</textarea>";
}

echo "<input type='submit' value='Finished' name='save_edit'/>";
echo "</form>";

?>
```

And the update:

```
<?php

$a = $_POST['edit'];

foreach($a AS $id => $b){
    $b = mysql_real_escape_string($b);
    $id = mysql_real_escape_string($id);

    $sql = mysql_query("UPDATE intrebari set denumire_intrebare='$b' WHERE id='".$id."'"); // Using id field again
}

?>
```

Comment: hmm...the id='".$id."'... the fisrt id here what stands for??

Comment: I already explained in my answer, please read the answer again.